# How do I get earrings?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

So I've been trying out some gunner weapons and ended up liking the bow a lot. I tried putting a set together in [Athena's ASS](http://forums.minegarde.com/topic/7348-athenas-ass-for-mh4g-and-mh4u/) but some of the results need something called [Barrage Earring](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/armor/head/barrage-earring).

I've looked around a bunch on how to get this but the answers most people give are quite inconsistent. The only thing they agree on is that you get them through the arena somehow.

What exactly do you have to accomplish to receive this earring?

For completion, it would be nice to also know how to get [Sword Saint Earring](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/armor/head/sword-saint-earring) and [Hawkeye Earring](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/armor/head/hawkeye-earring) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sword Saint Earrings and Barrage Earrings are awarded for completing all G-rank arena quests with all weapons (no required ranks). The Hawkeye Earring is given after completing the Code 16010 episodic quest.

Comment: I've finished The Caravaneer's Challenge a while ago and I never got the Hawkeye Earring. Are you sure you don't mean The Master's Test?

Comment: Whoops, it's neither. The Hawkeye Earring is received from completing an episodic quest.

Comment: That's the episode quest that came out earlier this month, right?

Comment: I believe so, yes.

Comment: So I have to do every single arena quest 5 times? Ugh

Comment: I've heard from some people that you only have to complete every G rank arena quest with all weapons and not the low/high rank ones. Can you confirm?